# Impossible to install Spring Roo 2 in macOS Mojave 10.14

Tags: spring-roo

I was trying to install Spring Roo 2.0.0.RELEASE in macOS Mojave 10.14 (Java 11) in STS IDE with no success.

In STS (3.9.7.RELEASE) the error while adding IDE Extension 'Spring Roo (current production release)' is 'The following connectors are not available: Spring Roo (current production release)'. I pressed continue, but still no success. I have tried multiple times in two days.

Has somebody managed to lunch Spring Roo 2 in macOS Mojave 10.14 in STS IDE?

(SOLVED BY REMOVING ALL JAVA VERSIONS FROM macOS APART FROM JAVA 8)

Comment: I have finally managed to launch Spring Roo 2 in STS IDE (3.9.7.RELEASE) by removing all java versions apart from 8 from my mac. I did not use window 'Dashboard' with button "IDE EXTENSIONS'.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the vm by adding a line to sts.ini:

```
...
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-vmargs ...
```

to list the installed vm's you may use this shell command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

if you use roo in the shell, select the correct vm before using it:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```